# how to optimize image like Facebook and WhatApp does?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I want to optimize the Image file size like whatsapp and facebook are doing. I have send 5MB Image on whatsapp, And received image has size of 80KB. Received image looks identical to the original ones but resolution is less than the original one.

I tried almost all the source codes of android image compression available on stackoverflow but that doesn't work for me. And then i came across [this link](http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/) to optimize the image, which is doing good work but still not getting the result like whatsapp.

How can i achieve maximum image compression without degrading the quality of image, Same like whatsapp did?

Answer with a source code will be very helpful.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: May try this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/re-size-and-compress-image-in-android-studio/

Comment: The only way to achieve it is using `inSampleSize` in a `Bitmap`. The link you specified in your answer calculates that factor by specifying a target max width and height. You might try to decrease them and see if you get better results.

Comment: WhatsApp does use lossy compression, the image quality decreases drastically. Don't expect to get this size improvement with just lossless algorithms...

Comment: sorry to mess with an old thread , was curious , does whatsapp/fb reduce quality at client end (like android app) or at server end ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode Image (bitmap)

Here is the code.

```
public Bitmap  decodeFile(String path) {
        // Decode image size
        int orientation;
        try {
            if (path == null) {
                return null ;
            }
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 0;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale++;
            }
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
            Bitmap bitmap = bm;
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
            orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

            Log.e("orientation", "" + orientation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight(), null, true);
            ImageViewChooseImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            bitmapfinal = bitmap;
            return bitmap ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image into **Bitmap and use compress()** method to compress it to a certain quality.
To maintain the quality of image, reduce it using **aspect ratio** of its height and width.you can use below code: where data is the byte array of image

```
Bitmap screen = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                    data.length);
            float oHeight = screen.getHeight();
            float oWidth = screen.getWidth();
            float aspectRatio = oWidth / oHeight;
            int newHeight = 0;
            int newWidth = 0;
            newHeight = 450;
            newWidth = (int) (newHeight * aspectRatio);
            screen = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(screen, newWidth, newHeight,
                    true);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            screen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
```

Comment: it depends on your requirement, like just maintain width-height and importantly increase the integer value from 50 to above in compress() method

Comment: yes but problem is it not give the quality like whatsapp n facebook gives it looses its quality very badly if we decreases the value 50,,40,,30 and so on

Comment: @Nish8900 Did you check the link that i provided in above question? Setting the quality level 50 reduce the image size but also degrade the quality of image, i want to reduce the image size while maintaining image quality.

Comment: Above answer is not a solution to my problem. i already did that thing in my code, which is given in the link of my question.

Comment: have integer value 80 in compress() and also maintain height according to the display